# how to test appLaunchURL of apple wallet pass

Tags: wallet, passkit

I'm developing Wallet Pass feature for my app, and the generated pass including `appLaunchURL`  and `associatedStoreIdentifiers`. After installed into Wallet and I clicked the icon in the bottom left corner, it pops up my app's App Store page instead of opening my app. So how can I test within developing app? And how to test open `appLaunchURL`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Also, what was the `appLaunchURL` and `associatedStoreIdentifiers` used?

Answer (score 0):

The app receives this URL in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:openURL:options: methods of its app delegate.

Have you implemented these methods?

Comment: Is the pass you created a Payment Pass?